# The code I write with /usr/bin/curl works, but the code I write with php curl is not working. Where am I making a mistake?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I have written two code scripts below on the terminal I'm working on, I'm writing with php doesn't work and I'm getting a missing parameter alert.

```
Terminal: /usr/bin/curl -s -X POST "https://api.xxxxxxx.com/action.json?type=modifycontact&resellerno=3040267&resellerpwd=xxxxxxx&lang=tr&responsetype=json" -d "registrycode=81386095&ownercontactid=81045261&admincontactid=81045261&billcontactid=81045261&techcontactid=81045261"

PHP: 
$url = "https://api.xxxxxxx.com/action.json?type=modifycontact&resellerno=3040267&resellerpwd=xxxxxxx&lang=tr&responsetype=json";
$value = "registrycode=81386095&ownercontactid=81045261&admincontactid=81045261&billcontactid=81045261&techcontactid=81045261";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $value);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, FALSE); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
        //$son = array();
        $sonlu = curl_exec($ch);
        $son['sonuc'] = (isset($sonlu) AND !empty($sonlu)) ? $sonlu : json_encode($sunucuhata);
        $son['httpcode'] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $son['error'] = curl_error($ch);
        $son['errorno'] = curl_errno($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
print_r($son);

Terminal response: {"status":"success","description":"OK"}

PHP response: Array
(
    [sonuc] => {"status":"error","description":"4553 missing parameter"}
    [httpcode] => 200
    [error] => 
    [errorno] => 0
)
```

Comment: httpcode => 200, your curl are executing correctly. The problem are on your $son['sonuc'] assignation, if the curl gives you no content, you're doing a json_encode of a inexistent? variable. Try to do first a print_r of $sonlu for check result from curl.

Comment: Your php code looks equal to the terminal version. Is there an API documentation which explains the error message "4553 missing parameter"?

Comment: protip, this would be prettier: http://paste.debian.net/plain/1057979

Comment: I did what Hanshenrik said and error messages: registrycode required.

Comment: You could ask the API support what error "4553 missing parameter" means, if there is no documentation?

Comment: We sent the same parameters but we didn't find out what kind of problem this has got on two different curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message does not come from curl, its the API response. So the API need something.

You can check if there is a documentation for this API which explains the error message with more details.

The only difference i see between terminal curl and php: php dont sets a USER AGENT header by default. Maybe this header is missing in your request. I dont know your curl version, but something like this could work:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'curl/7.61.1');
```

**UPDATE:** as mentioned by [hanshenrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1067003/hanshenrik)

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'curl/' . curl_version()['version']);
```

Comment: actually to accurately mimic curl cli's useragent, use  ```curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'curl/'.(curl_version()["version"]));```

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. Still not working with PHP.